# How can I add click listener on google map places Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

[please see this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVcMw.png)
When I click on a place this popup appears. I want to add a click listener for this to get the location data like lat long, formatted address etc.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) or another AngularJS module for Google Maps ([angular google maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/), ...).

Below some Angular examples (good obviously also for Ionic):

https://ngmap.github.io/#/!infowindow_ng_click.html

http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/demo